# Почему стили для input type="range" (бегунка) не применяется?

Tags: html, css, input, range

Бегунок в данном примере должен быть красного цвета из-за `background: red;` , но он остаётся синим:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.slider {  
  border: 0;  
  outline: 0;  
  width: 100px;  
  background: red;  
}  

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  appearance: none; 
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: red; 
  cursor: pointer; 
} 

.slider::-moz-range-thumb { 
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: red; 
  cursor: pointer; 
} 

.slider::-ms-thumb { 
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: red; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: на FF 91 все работает. укажите хоть свой браузер и его версию. если бодаетесь с эджем, возможно требуется это `::-ms-tooltip {display: none;}` более подробно можете потичать тут: https://css-tricks.com/sliding-nightmare-understanding-range-input/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для "хромоподобных" браузеров необходимо указывать свойство `appearance: none`, как псевдоэлементам, так и самому элементу `<input>`:

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-ms-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил только